# After pushViewController, how to disable the backBarButtonItem?

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationitem

After pushViewController, how to disable the backBarButtonItem, that going back will not be possible?

Comment: Perhaps, if you don't want the user to be able to go back, then the better decision is not to use a navigation controller? Is this a conditional thing?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES

Comment: I did that. But for some reason the back button still appears until I try to tap it. Then it disappears. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

if you use a storyboard, click Navigation Item and add "hidesBackButton" path into the Key Path Attributes tag.

[image]

Answer (score -2):

I ran into this issue and used following to hide the nav bar:

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden: YES animated:YES];
```